# Big discrepancy in used size between Drive Properties and All Files Properties

Tags: disk-management

I have two different microSD cards which show a big discrepancy between the total size used when shown in Drive Properties and when shown in All Folders/Files Properties.  Below is an example.

[image: F: Drive Properties]

[image: All Folders & Files in F: Drive Properties]

The F: Drive Properties say 13.5GB is used, but when I go into the F: drive and selected all Folders/Files, Properties show only 7.68GB.  There is a difference of more than 5GB.

Computer Disk Manager says F: has a FAT32 partition of 31.24GB and an unallocated 7.68MB partition.

My Files Explorer is showing hidden and system files.

Where are the missing gigabytes?

Comment: Check what `Disk cleanup` under the Tools tab in Properties comes up with.

Comment: Thanks. Under Tools there're only Check (checked and no errors) and Optimize (optimization not available for this drive).

Comment: You could possibly use a cluster explorer aka a defragger that works under fat32 that the gui would allow you to see what is in each cluster. (but not to defrag with it)  Another method i would use would be to copy all needed files off of it (because you need to backup anyway) Then format the card again, and copy needed files back. It would be good before doing that to make sure of 2 things, the files you copy off work proper, and everything you will possibly need is there.

Answer (score 1):

The difference might be [LOST.DIR](http://androidforums.com/threads/lost-dir-what-is-it.447049/), which is a recovery directory, not necessarily accessible under Windows.

If you no longer need the data on the card, you could reformat it (not *Quick*) to get back the storage. You could also [delete the LOST.DIR](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-droid-incredible/13500-delete-lost-dir-get-memory-back.html).

Comment: I deleted LOST.DIR and All Files now show 13.5GB used!  One folder less, but more space consumed.  A bit weird, but at least the total now tallies.  What sort of folder can that be?